# How can I print the numbers which have a sum that equals the cube of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = 5
cube = n**3

def get_sum(n):
    a1 = n * (n - 1) + 1
    for i in range(a1, cube, 2):
        print(i, end='+')


print(f'{get_sum(n)}')
print(cube)
```

I have output:

```
21+23+25+27+29+31+33+35+37+39+41+43+45+47+49+51+53+55+57+59+61+63+65+67+69+71+73+75+77+79+81+83+85+87+89+91+93+95+97+99+101+103+105+107+109+111+113+115+117+119+121+123+None
125
```

How can I get a range till 29 so the sum of these numbers will be equal to cube in Python?

For example, `21+23+25+27+29 = 5^3`

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient approach:
Keep a variable that tracks the current sum to check if we need to break the loop or not (as mentioned in the other answers).

Efficient Approach:
n^3 can be expressed as a sum of n odd integers, which are symmetric about n^2. Examples:

```
3^3 = 7+9+11 (symmetric about 9)  
4^3 = 13+15+17+19 (symmetric about 16)  
5^3 = 21+23+25+27+29 (symmetric about 25)
```

Use this approach to get a simpler algorithm

Answer (score 0):

first, no need to write `print(f'{get_sum(n)}')` since your function doesn't return anything except `None` which you can see in your output, `get_sum(n)` is enough.

since you are always looping n times, you can simplify your condition, in my solution I used a while loop with a `sum` variable to keep tabs with the current sum of numbers.

you can apply the same logic with a for loop of course, this is just my implementation.

```
def get_sum(n):
    a1 = n * (n - 1) + 1
    sum = a1
    while sum < cube:
        print(a1, end='+')
        a1+=2
        sum+=a1
    print(a1, end='=') 
    
n = 5
cube = n**3
get_sum(n)
print(cube)
```

output:

```
21+23+25+27+29=125
```